# DataGridView.DisplayedRowCount only works if DataGridView is visible

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

DisplayedRowCount() of type DataGridView returns 0 if the parent form or the datagridview itself is not visible. E.g. this is the case in the constructor of the parent form (see code below). Is there an alternative function, that also works if the datagridview is invisible? So I want to know the number of visible rows before I make them visible.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();

    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();

      dgv.Parent = this;
      dgv.Columns.Add("col1", "col1");
      dgv.Columns.Add("col2", "col2");

      for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        dgv.Rows.Add(i, i);

      int drc = dgv.DisplayedRowCount(false);
      MessageBox.Show(drc.ToString());    // returns 0
    }

    protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)
    {
      base.OnShown(e);
      int drc = dgv.DisplayedRowCount(false);
      MessageBox.Show(drc.ToString());    // returns 4
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there it a clean way to do this. How should the DataGridView know the exact number of rows that will be displayed to the user before it is actually displayed? The result 0 of DisplayedRowCount() is absolutely correct in this sense.

However, depending on your requirements, you might display the form with Form.Opacity set to 0, so it would be invisible to the user.